# illegal character '\u201c' in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following scala script:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, NullWritable}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleApp")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://master-full:54310/tera-output")
        val splits = file.map(word => word.toLong)
        splits.map(row => (NullWritable.get(), new LongWritable(row))).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(“hdfs://master-full:54310/output/",classOf[NullWritable],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable,LongWritable]])
    }
}
```

When I am trying to compile it, I am getting the following errors:

```
[error] /home/cloud-user/SparkWordCount/src/main/scala/WordCount.scala:13: illegal character '\u201c'
[error]         splits.map(row => (NullWritable.get(), new LongWritable(row))).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(“hdfs://master-full:54310/output/",classOf[NullWritable],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable,LongWritable]])
[error]                                                                                               ^
[error] /home/cloud-user/SparkWordCount/src/main/scala/WordCount.scala:14: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error]     }
[error]     ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I have a file simple.sbt, which lists the dependencies:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

After fixing the quote problem, as correctly pointed out, I am getting this error:

```
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/home/cloud-user/SparkWordCount/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/cloud-user/SparkWordCount/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/cloud-user/SparkWordCount/src/main/scala/WordCount.scala:15: not found: type TextOutputFormat
[error]         splits.map(row => (NullWritable.get(), new LongWritable(row))).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://master-full:54310/output/",classOf[NullWritable],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable,LongWritable]])
[error]                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, NullWritable}
object SimpleApp {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
            val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://master-full:54310/tera-output")
        val splits = file.map(word => word.toLong)
        splits.map(row => (NullWritable.get(), new LongWritable(row))).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://master-full:54310/output/",classOf[NullWritable],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable,LongWritable]])
    }
}
```

It looks like you have the wrong kind of quotation mark in the offending line (`“` instead of `"`).

Comment: Thanks! that fixed one error, I didn't notice the wrong quote.

Comment: @user3033194 for the other one, you seem to be missing a closing ), I will have a look at where exactly but unfortunately it will take a bit until I have time.

Comment: Actually, both those earlier errors disappeared, but a new one appeared. I have edited my post. Something wrong with TextOutputFormat.

Comment: Done! I missed an import for TextOutputFormat...thanks a ton!!